# SharePoint 2010 Search crawl gatherer's temp folder got disappeared

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

I have 1 application server with SharePoint 2010 SP1 installed and another for Database SQL server 2008 R2. Suddenly the Temp folder for search crawl got disappeared and due to this search crawling got failed. It was fixed by manually creating those temp folders.

But after few months temp folders again got disappeared. 
We are not able to find root cause and permanent fix for this issue.
It seems search service got corrupted and need to rebuild again.
Does anyone has faced this issue. I don't prefer rebuilding the search application as this issue is on Production server. Please let me know your views.